# Handle a file download triggered by the click of a button

Tags: python, python-2.7, download, mechanize

I want to programmatically download a file who's url I do not have. On a regular browser once you click a button the browser it usually asks if you want to save, open or cancel. However doing the browsing, filling text fields, and pressing buttons through python using mechanize. How can I save this file into my computer after I click the button using mechanize?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use `retrieve` to open the url the button points to.

```
Downloading a file:

# Download
f = br.retrieve('http://www.google.com.br/intl/pt-BR_br/images/logo.gif')[0]
print f
fh = open(f)

fh.read() # < this will give you the content
```

you can open up a file where you want to save it to your computer

```
 with open('/path/to/save', 'w') as f:
    f.write(fh.read())
```

http://stockrt.github.com/p/emulating-a-browser-in-python-with-mechanize/

Comment: So how would I save the file after I have the link if retrieve were to give me such link? Although I think it is giving me the file itself already. More experimenting will tell me exactly what I'm getting. How would I save it the file my computer?

Comment: OH also the button is a form so there is no direct link I can access